# HTML5 video, Zend Framework 3 and Google Chrome: Bad Slider and Slow Dispatch

Tags: html, video, slider, dispatch, zend-framework3

The page with the video takes a long time (nearly a minute) to refresh 
or dispatch to another page.  Also the video slider is not working in Chrome.
This only happens with Zend Framework.  If I use just a regular HTML page
everything works fine.

Comment: I am going to create a git repo that shows the problem.  Please give me a moment.

Comment: Are you serving the video file through PHP by any chance?

Comment: Yes I was.  That was the problem.